# AWS Amplify Build Time Out Error: got stuck at Frontend while running gulpfile.js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, gulp, hosting, aws-amplify

I moved from manual deployment to automatic CI/CD with my Github repo, In manual deployment, it was working with out any issues. After connecting the main repo and starting the build, it's not getting completed at the Frontend provision.

I'm getting the build timeout error with 30 min default time setting and then increasing it to 120 min in environmental variables override. It's still taking so much time.

On my local machine: it just takes <5 min to build without any errors.[Error log of amplify build page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4EIX.png)

I see from the build log that: after running commands in gulpfile.js, it's getting stuck.

Build Settings file:

```html
version: 1
env:
  variables:
    VERSION_AMPLIFY: 8.3.0
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm i -g @aws-amplify/cli@${VERSION_AMPLIFY}
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
        - node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

[Console Error Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rme59.png)

Comment: how did you manage to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while configuring my Amplify deployment. The issue was due to an unnecessary step in the `amplify.yml` file that Amplify auto-generated for me.

Try removing this line from the front-end build step and try again:

```
- node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
```

In my case, this line started a dev server *after* I built the appplication causing the frontend build process to hang and never finish. By removing that line, you avoid starting a dev server after you build, and the build step should succeed.

These are the relevant scripts in my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp build --env production",
  }
```

These commands are all equivalent, and not needed to build your application for deployment:

- `yarn run dev`
- `gulp`
- `node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js`